# The usage of the word makeshift: "a makeshift volcano as a school science project"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I came across this following sentence [here](http://abcnews.go.com/US/florida-girl-arrested-similar-circumstances-ahmed-mohamed-advice/story?id=33838741) but I could not understand what she means by **makeshift** science project.

> Wilmot, now 19, said that in April 2013 she brought a science project
>    to school in Bartow, Florida -- a **makeshift** volcano that she was very
>    excited to show her teacher.

Volcano is what she did for the science project.

Does she imply her project was not well prepared so it did not look like a real volcano already or is this a standard usage for different meaning than being temporary?

http://abcnews.go.com/US/florida-girl-arrested-similar-circumstances-ahmed-mohamed-advice/story?id=33838741

Answer (score 2):

In this context it would mean 'Improvised'. Possibly she made the volcano out of material that she had lying around at the time.

Comment: As opposed to providing molten magma?

Comment: Yeah she's not really into pleonasms